# How does playframework migrations work with multiple servers?

Tags: scala, playframework

If I have migrations that need to be run in production, if my play app is being deployed to say 20 servers, how will migrations be managed?

Won't the migrations be attempted 20 times on each server?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your setup.

If each of your application have migration enabled unconditionally each instant will attempt to migrate.

If you have some config passed into instance (e.g. you use env vars to set which migrations are run in [config](https://www.playframework.com/modules/migrate-1.3.2/home#aConfigurationa)), then these that have migration enabled will run time.

No magic automatically makes sure that only one instance run migrations.

On the positive side SQL migrations are run in transactions, and migration libraries store the current version in DB and run the diff between current and target version, so it shouldn't break you DB, at worst case 2 migrations run at once make one of attempts fail with exception, but DB would still end up with a valid version. Perhaps instance would crash but on next run it would be ok.

So, *usually* the worst that can happen (depends on configuration) is some instances failing and needing restart and then working, but if you are afraid that your might not be the cases use proper configuration in you cluster/host to enable migration only in one instance and not the others.

This advice is not Play-specific, it's the same if you use Flyway or whatever.